# Python how to use idxmax() to get the full row values but based on a condition on a specific field

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I need to get the maximum temperature of a specific region in the data frame. By simply applying the following:

```
df.loc[(df['Max Temperature'].idxmax())]
```

It is working as the result is:

> ```
> Date                   2012-07-19 00:00:00
>
> Precipitation [mm]                       0
>
> Average Temperature                  28.28
>
> Max Temperature                      39.42
>
> MonthName                             July
>
> Day                                     19
>
> MonthNbr                                 7
>
> Year                                  2012
>
> Area                                Bekaa
>
> AvgTest                              28.28
>
> Name: 1176, dtype: object
> ```

I need to get the row of the maximum value but for a specific area. I tried to add a condition as follows:

```
df.loc[df['Max Temperature']==df['Max Temperature'].max() & df['Area']=='Fanar, Beirut']
```

Bu got the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and
> scalar of type [bool]

Answer (score 2):

Because precedence of operators `==` and `&` add `()`, also if need select all columns `loc` should be omitted:

```
df[(df['Max Temperature']==df['Max Temperature'].max()) & (df['Area']=='Fanar, Beirut')]
```

Or use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
df[df['Max Temperature'].eq(df['Max Temperature'].max())&df['Area'].eq('Fanar, Beirut')]
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `&`, you must enclose the conditions in parentheses:

```
df.loc[(df['Max Temperature']==df['Max Temperature'].max()) & (df['Area']=='Fanar, Beirut')]
```